# Problemas com leitura do banco de dados [SQLite]

Tags: android, sqlite

Dia número 3. O app insiste em "crashar" em sua inicialização e a
frustração é forte no momento.
O problema, acredito eu, se encontra no método getFromDb(), mais especificamente na linha onde chamo o método db.getReadableDatabase()
uma vez que o app roda NORMALMENTE sem o trecho entre " /*   */ "
destacado no código abaixo.

Segue o código problemático.

```
    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "productsManager";
    private static final String TABLE_PRODUCTS = "products";

    private static final String _PRODUCT = "product";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE products (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, product TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PRODUCTS);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addToDb(String product){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues valor = new ContentValues();
        valor.put(_PRODUCT, product);

        db.insert(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, valor);
        db.close();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getFromDb(){
        ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
/*        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_PRODUCTS, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do{
                stringList.add(cursor.getString(1));
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();*/
        return  stringList;
    }
}
```

Por favor alguém sabe dizer o que esta errado?
Se preciso posso adicionar posteriormente mais informações.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o log de erros.

Comment: Genial Ramaral! Li o log de erros e o problema era que o método getFromDb() estava sendo chamado para um objeto ArrayList não instanciado na main_activity... Você ganhou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É, realmente falta informação, mas pelo que pude ver no codigo postado, vc deveria ter feito algo tipo:

```
   public ArrayList<String> getFromDb(){
    ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sqlCmd = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_PRODUCTS+";";
    // se voce tiver alguma clausula WHERE, acrecenta a mesma na linha acima
    Cursor cursor = db.query(sqlCmd);

    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        do{
          stringList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("codigo")));
          stringList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("descricao")));
          stringList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("categoria")));
          stringList.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("preco")));
            // e quantos campos mais voce quiser, lembrando que:
            // ...(getColumnIndex('campo') se refere ao indice de uma
            // coluna da tabela referenciada pelo seu nome
        }while(cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return  stringList;
}
```

Se der algum problema, avisa
no caso de manipulação de dados em um db, seja ele qual for, a boa pratica insiste em criar variaveis constantes com os nomes da tabelas, fica mais facil de voce manipular seu codigo, visto que sendo uma variavel constante e a mesma sendo referenciada em varios pontos do codigo, se voce mudar a constante voce consequentemente vai mudar tambem as suas referencias.

Comment: Obrigado pelo tempo e pelas dicas.Quanto a sua função, ela apresenta o mesmo problema que a minha, o método this.getReadableDatabase que faz o app crashar antes que possa executar as outras instruções...

Comment: esse problema deve ser porque voce precisa instanciar a classe "DatabaseHandler" primeiro na activity que chama ela, algo tipo `List<String> dados = new ArrayList<String>(); DabaseHandler meudb = new DatabaseHandler;` depois disso, como o o metodo getFromDb() retorna um arraylist, voce chama ele usando `dados = getFromDb();`
tenta ai e retorna se for isso pra eu editar a resposta.

Comment: O problema era exatamente esse. O próprio log de erros informou e eu não sabia lê-lo.

Comment: bom que tenha resolvido man, voce tambem pode usar `db.rawQuery(sql, null);`como na dica do amigo @Felipe xavier que funciona tambem

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou usar o rawQuery ao inves do query?

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
String query = "SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_PRODUCTS;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
```

Comment: pois é, problema não pode ser esse, prq o programa não consegue passar da instrução this.getReadableDatabase()